# How do I include a file dynamically into a TeamCity build

Tags: teamcity, devops, teamcity-9.0

I am fairly new to TeamCity and have recently been tasked with creating various builds, which I have done with no real issues.

What I am trying to do now though is include an external text file into the build output.

The external text file will be received from a service call made during the build.

These are my intended build steps:

1. Check out solution.
2. Restore packages.
3. Run tests.
4. Call web service with a configurable parameter and receive text file back.
5. Include text file in build.
6. Deploy.

Steps 1,2,3 and 6 are covered.

What are my options here? I must confess I do not really know where to begin.
I've spent some time today googling but it has been tricky getting the correct search term to return information on what I am trying to achieve.

I've seen some confusing articles on a 'meta runner'.

Any pointers to get me started in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use a TeamCity command line build step - https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Command+Line

I assume you are using build steps for all the other steps you listed so this is simply another of those.

The command line process would run somewhere under your checkout folder and thus anything it downloads would be made available as an artifact for your build

Comment: Thanks for that.  That gives me somewhere to start.